# generate_series() failed in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, calendar, amazon-redshift, generate-series

I worked well in DBeaver with code

```sql
INSERT INTO table_dates(calendar_date, day_of_week)
SELECT 
    generate_series::date as calendar_date,
    To_Char(generate_series, 'Dy') as. day_of_week
FROM generate_series(to_timestamp('1990-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd'), to_timestamp('2050-12-31 00:00:00' ,'yyyy/mm/dd') ,'1 day')
```

But I got error when I worked in Redshift, it looks like Redshift is not supported

> generate_series()
> Error: function generate_series(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone, "unknown") does not exist
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

I expect the result look like:

````
calendar_date  calendar_date  
1990-01-01  Mon
1990-01-02  Tue
1990-01-03  Wed
1990-01-04  Thu
1990-01-05  Fri
1990-01-06  Sat
1990-01-07  Sun
1990-01-08  Mon
1990-01-09  Tue
1990-01-10  Wed
1990-01-11  Thu
1990-01-12  Fri
1990-01-13  Sat
...
2050-12-31  Sat
```
````

Comment: This code just work for calendar date `SELECT 
    '1990-01-01' :: DATE + generate_series AS calendar_date
    FROM generate_series(0,30000,1);` But when I put `insert into table`, it still got error: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables

Comment: The `generate_series()` function will only run on the Leader Node. It cannot be used in any operation that acts on a table. Yes, this is unfortunate. If you search enough, you'll find clever ways that people have found alternate ways to generate a series of numbers, including simply having a table of numbers.